# MySQL: Combining two repetitive queries to make WHERE clause dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, where-clause

How can I combine these two queries into one so I don't have to repeat the same lines again and again?

```
if(empty($cat_id))
{
    $sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM root_category_contacts
    ORDER by cat_order ASC
    ";

    $items_category = $connection->fetch_all($sql);
}
else
{
    $sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM root_category_contacts
    WHERE root_category_contacts.cat_id != ?
    ORDER by cat_order ASC
    ";

    $items_category = $connection->fetch_all($sql,array($cat_id));
}
```

I don't need `WHERE` clause when I don't have the `cat_id`.

Is it feasible?

Comment: Why would you be repeating the lines again and again? Are you saying there are a lot of similar queries where you have this issue, or do you mean just the one repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if ? is null or equals cat_id. Something like this:

**Edit** based on xdazz's comment. And assuming that cat_id > 0

```
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM root_category_contacts
WHERE root_category_contacts.cat_id != ?
ORDER by cat_order ASC"

if(empty($cat_id)) {
    $cat_id = 0;
}

$items_category = $connection->fetch_all($sql,array($cat_id));
```

Comment: this results an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== NULL OR root_category_members.cat_id != '1' ORDER by cat_order A' at line 3`

Comment: oops it should be `IS NULL` not `== NULL` :-) Fixed now.

Comment: got it! thanks. can I ask - what does it mean `WHERE ? IS NULL`?

the placeholder will be replace with a number when the `cat_id` is not empty. so for instance, `WHERE '2' IS NULL` - then what does this mean? I don't quite understand it...

Comment: If cat_id = 2. Then 2 is not null, so then it will check the other half of the OR statement (`root_category_contacts.cat_id != 2`) If that is true then it will return that row. You may have to adjust the query a little to get the correct results.

Comment: I got the result I want with this answer. No other adjustments needed. I just want to understand the query in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob Eggers: What about `$cat_id=0`, 0 is not null, but empty($cat_id) is true. It violate the OP's logic. So does the empty string.

Comment: @xdazz good point. I'll fix that. Though I did say the query might need adjustments.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(empty($cat_id)) $where = "";
else $where = "WHERE root_category_contacts.cat_id != '$cat_id'"

$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM root_category_contacts
    $where
    ORDER by cat_order ASC
    ";

$items_category = $connection->fetch_all($sql);
```

Comment: You lose the benefits of his method (Cached query plan, protrection from sql injection) if you do use dynamic sql like this.

Comment: you are absolutly right. I thought about it too late. (but I'm surprised that mysql plan still can't cache a query with variable "strings" inside). However, for sql injections, your 200% right.